# The ViewGroup can still scroll when I set it can scroll when getScrollX()>=0

Tags: android

Here is my Code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        int x=(int)event.getX();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            mLastX = x;
            mStart = getScrollX();
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            if (!mScroller.isFinished()) {
                mScroller.abortAnimation();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: getScrollX-->"+getScrollX());
            int dx=mLastX-x;
            if(getScrollX()>=0&&getScrollX()<mSlideViewWidth){
                scrollBy(dx,0);
            }
            mLastX=x;
        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            mEnd = getScrollX();
            if(getScrollX()<0){
                mScroller.startScroll(getScrollX(),0,-mEnd,0);
            }
        }
        postInvalidate();
        return true;
    }
```

When I slide the screen to the left ,ScrollX is less than 0,so the scrollby method should not be called.But when I slide the screen to the left, ViewGroup can still move a short distance to the left.
I guess the solution might have something to do with the getScrollX method.
But because I've only recently learned Custom view,I hava no idea to deal with this.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.
[Problem description gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6RvD.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a animation problem, or you have an translate effect still going before the last scrollX OR probably your case, the `dx` value + `getScrollX()` in your last iteration is bigger  than 0, your solution is to see if you near the edge and adjust `dx` to be the exact amount of `-getScrollX()` if it's bigger.

```
  int dx=mLastX-x;
  if (dx < -getScrollX()) dx = -getScrollX(); //not tested but should work
  if(getScrollX()>=0&&getScrollX()<mSlideViewWidth)
    scrollBy(dx,0);
```